# In C++ CLI, how to use/declare a static int array accessible to all functions in the source file?

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

In C++/CLI, how to declare the C equivalent of "static int array[400]" where array is accessible to all functions in the source file -- without getting the error "a member of a managed class cannot be a standard array"?

A non-array declaration, like "static int age", works fine, but not arrays.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "all functions in the source file" with "all member functions of a single class".  Which do you actually want?

Comment: Visual Studio, via its form designer, created a .h file which contains functions it created (e.g., for buttons) plus static functions that I've added (which I call from the button functions).  I'd like my added functions to be able to access a static integer array (just as they are now able to access static integer variables that I added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't actually have any notion of "source file".  Instead there's a "compilation unit" which consists of the file that the compiler starts processing (because it was specified on the command-line) AND all files found from that file via `#include`, recursively.

In C++ you can use exactly the same syntax that worked in C:

```
static int array[400];
```

but it's preferred to use an anonymous namespace rather than global-scoped `static`:

```
namespace
{
    int array[400];
}
```

Note that you shouldn't be putting these lines inside of a `class` or `ref class` block, they go at file scope.  And they shouldn't be in a header file, which is where most `class` or `ref class` definitions are found, because header files are intended to be included into multiple compilation units and doing that will lead to having a bunch of independent copies of the same variable, which is bound to cause confusion.

---

If on the other hand your need is not related to compilation units at all, and you want a variable shared between all member functions in the class, no matter where they may be defined or `#included`, then you should use a static data member.  In C++/CLI, a data member of a managed class has to be itself managed data, so use [the C++/CLI syntax for a .NET array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170):

```
cli::array<int>^ array = gcnew cli::array<int>(400);
```

For static data members of managed types, C++/CLI acts more like C# than C++ and you can write the initial value inline:

```
ref class MyCppCliClass
{
    static cli::array<int>^ array = gcnew cli::array<int>(400);
};
```